# Build multiple html pages within ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-analytics, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli project that currently does not run at all in IE<10. I still want to be able to track when users come to the site from these unsupported browsers as part of our business case so I still have a need for Google Analytics to run.

I have created an IE specific page which is almost an exact copy of `app/index.html` but I have removed the JavaScripts from getting downloaded so ember does not ever get run. This page simply displays that the user is using an unsupported browser and then logs the page visit to GA.

I want to be able to compile helpers such as `{{content-for 'head'}}` in this IE page because there are a few things I need to bring into the file, namely the GA script along with our specific tracking code that is in the environments file, so it is a necessity that it is part of the build process.

I was more recently told to use conditional comments but having scoured [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I have discovered these are no longer supported so I don't want to head down that road.

I have saved this file as `app/ie.html` but it does not get included in the build. How can I configure ember-cli to include this file?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have a `ie.html` file that you want to get copied into the `dist` folder. You can use `app.import` in the `Brofile.js` for that.

But `app.import` currently will only work with files inside either `bower_components` or the `vendor` directory. [**You can read here about this.**](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3890)

What you can do is copy your `ie.html` file into the `vendor` folder like `vendor/ieCompat/ie.html`

Then inside the `Brocfile` you can import like

```
app.import('vendor/ieCompat/ie.html', {destDir: ''});
```

Comment: What this does not do is pull in code when I use `{{content-for 'scripts'}}`. It instead copies the file leaving the {{content-for 'scripts'}} as is in plain text

Comment: You may need to use this addon https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-inline-content but im not completely sure how.